# Can an active directory group indirectly include itself in a cycle?

Tags: security, active-directory, recursive

**Is it possible for a group to directly or indirectly include itself?**

In other words, is it possible for the following structure to be created:

> `Group-A`
>     `└─ Group-B`
>              `└─ Group-C`
>                       `└─ Group-A`  (recursive cycle)

Does AD detect and prevent such cases, or does it allow them and handle the recursive cycle.

If I had administrative access to an AD forest, and I wasn't afraid of unravelling the fabric of reality, I would test this myself. Google, sadly - has been of little help in answering this question ... although I may not be making the proper incantation in the search input box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Directly:**  No, an error is returned that `A group cannot be a member of itself`

**Indirectly:** There is nothing preventing this from happening in Active Directory, and is known as [Circular Group Nesting](http://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enCA291CA303&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=circular+group+nesting).

Answer (score 2):

I have a different experience.  If you use the Active Directory Users and Computers and do a right-click on a group then select "Add to a Group", you can enter the name of the group and the add succeeds, effectively making a group a member of itself.